# QTableWidget return current item but return previous value when clicked

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qlineedit

Im trying to write function: when click to one value in QtableWidget, this value will show up on lineEdit. But i have a problem: the return value is previous value and i must click one more time,lineEdit just returns the current value.

- Ex: two value: 0,1. frist click (value 0): return empty, 2nd click (value 0): return 0, 3rd click (value 1): return 0, 4th click(value 1): return 1.
- My code:

```
    class ClickableList(QTableWidget):
        clicked = pyqtSignal()
        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            self.clicked.emit()
            QTableWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event) 
    class Ui_FormCam(object):
        def setupUi(self, Form):
            

             ...
        
             self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
             self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
             self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
             ...
             self.tableWidget = ClickableList(Form)
             self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 20, 256, 192))
             self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
             self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        
             item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
             self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
             item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
             self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
             item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
             self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
             
             ...
             self.tableWidget.clicked.connect(self.getTextFromList)
             ...
       def getTextFromList(self):
             # print(self.tableWidget.item(0,0).text())
         self.lineEdit.setText(self.tableWidget.currentItem().text())
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you emitted the signal *before* calling the default implementation (which is responsible of updating the selection). Besides, QTableWidget already has a [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) signal, just like *any* Qt item view, so subclassing for that is pointless. You also should not edit pyuic files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin `.currentCellChanged` or `.currentItemChanged` signal instead of `.clicked` one then the callback will be called with the parameters of the old and new cell index if you use the cell version, or the old value and new value if you use the item version.

For example:

```
self.tableWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.getTextFromList)

def getTextFromList(self, old_value, new_value):
    self.lineEdit.setText(new_value.text())
```